# Java Spring 4 cookie secure attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Currently have java spring application in development and am working on securing it before publishing. Currently the cookie Does Not Contain The "secure" Attribute which is a security risk. In other versions of spring I would put this in the web.xml

```
<session-config>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>

<session-config>
    <cookie-config>
        <secure>true</secure>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

Can anyone help me translate this into java spring version 4? The cookie-config seems to be not valid for this version.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring as that is basic Servlet configuration and works regardless of using Spring or not. Get the `sessionCookieConfig` from the `ServletContext` and set the appropriate properties to what you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration you have mentioned above  belongs to servlet 3.0 spec. If your application is using spring session instead of servelet container session the params above wont make any impact.

Comment: Do you know how to set the secure attribute on the cookie generated by a java spring 4 application?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of setting secure cookie in web.xml, you can set it at tomcat configuration file.

Here I attached a link for how to set secure cookie in tomcat conf file.
https://geekflare.com/secure-cookie-flag-in-tomcat/

Comment: It's generally better to include code in your answer, not just links (which may become invalid if the link breaks.)